# iOS 15.7.3 - iPhone is busy: Making the device ready for development

Tags: ios, xcode

I recently updated iPhone to 15.7.3 and now it in unusable in Xcode 14.2 now. Xcode is indefinitely stuck in "iPhone is busy: Making the device ready for development"

I have done following and nothing helped so far

1. Installed Xcode 13.4.1 and the same problem
2. Removed all development apps from iPhone
3. Removed all derived data from Xcode
4. Rebooted iPhone couple of times
5. Rebooted Mac couple of times
6. Unpaired iPhone from the device and reconnected again without any luck.
7. Tried on both X86 MBP and M1 mini, both showing the same issue.
8. Checked `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport` folder. Folder for `15.7` present for 14.2 so that is not an issue too

There is a similar issue reported on Apple forum https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/714388 but without any concrete resolution. Xcode 14 missed 15.7.3  support but it was later fixed in 14.0.1

I am totally clueless, any hints?

Comment: Why someone wants to give this a negative and close vote without any explanation.

Comment: If you have an apple watch connected to that iPhone, turn it off. I had a similar issue a couple of times when it was trying to load debug symbols for the watch. That takes a lot of time apparently.

Comment: No accessories are connected, even I turned off bluetooth

Comment: Sometime you need to disconnect the cable , stop xCode, start xCode , connect iPhone cable, open device and simulator window, only then it start to enable device.

Answer (score 0):

Leave the phone connected for a while. It might take an hour until the data is completely transferred to the phone. When you do each step (open Xcode, connect iPhone) wait until each step will be completed.

Comment: the phone was connected overnight. Moreover, my another iPhone with ios 16 only took 5 mins

Comment: Check if the device is enabled for development. Google 'enable iPhone for development'.